# isight camera on quantal is erratic (macbook air 4,2)

Tags: 12.10, camera, macbook-air

I have a macbook air 4,2 (13" - 2011).  The isight camera has become rather erratic in quantal.  If I just pull up something like skype and go into the settings, things look fine.  The problem occurs when I am in an actual network video chat.  The other party sees me skipping, lagging, still video for 30 seconds at a time, etc.  Audio works without flaw during those times.  Also, in OS X in the same applications (skype and google plus), on the same network, things appear just fine.

I don't have hard evidence, but IIRC, this problem did not occur in precise.  I know that my video chat has worked in the past, and I believe that the quantal upgrade was the dividing line.

Is there some problem with the driver for the isight camera?  Some kind of settings that I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I think that there is a problem with your camera driver. Just check for updates and install them.